What is the most advisable database architecture (deterministic functions vs deterministic views)?
Our team is running into horrible run times due to context switching efficiencies for our queries because of the use of deterministic functions.
The team is split down the middle between allocating more resources to the database and refactoring our entire architecture from deterministic functions to a sort of "deterministic view" approach, as encapsulating the logic thats in the functions into views eliminates the context switching between the PLSQL engine and the SQL engine.
We have tried using some PRAGMA statements to boost efficiencies but have had very underwhelming results.
Allocating more resources to the server seems like diminishing returns.
But refactoring all our functions to views, while requiring a significant investment in time, seems like the most logical option. While yes, im aware what im describing is not a "true" deterministic functions, and im fairly sure there is no definition of a "deterministic view" these seem like the most appropriate descriptions of what we are looking to achieve.
While a deterministic function returns a single, repeatable output for a single same input. A deterministic view would return single repeatable value for every record that matches the predicate of the view logic.
Is this advisable or is there a third option I am missing to create repeatable, encapsulated logic for quick turnaround on creating queries.

How and when you are calling the functions, and would query the views, is going to matter - so there isn't going to be a simple generic answer. If you're sure the way you use the functions is otherwise as efficient as it can be then I'd suggest you do a proof of concept with your view approach to see if it actually solves your issue for your data.

What version of Oracle are you using? If you're using 21c or later, a SQL Macro for scalar expressions might be a decent third option. You could keep the functions, and then Oracle would re-write the queries using those functions to embed them in the SQL, eliminating the context switching.

Please provide a mocked up example of what you're doing (sample code, both function and driving query). Also, have you verified that your issue isn't SQL tuning within the function, but truly the context switching? SQL in PL/SQL called by SQL doesn't report itself and so isn't properly visible in ASH, but it could simply be a matter of tuning those SQL statements in those functions. And I assume you've already tried the PRAGMA UDF pragma?

I agree with @PaulW on optimizing the functions.  We use functions in our SQL extensively, and have great performance.  When we experience poor performance in a query using functions, we usually only need optimize poor performing function(s).  Unless your functions are atypically simple, you'll probably see bigger wins from optimizing functions than focusing on context switching.
